# Apache seems to redirect to domain name ever when not running

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, port, apache2, node.js

I'll preface this by saying I don't have a lot of experience with Apache.

But currently I am running a Node process that's listening on port 8080. However, when I access that port via 'ipaddress:8080', it redirects to the site domain name per the Apache config. The same thing happens with port 80 even though that's where nginx is running and it should redirect to a Node process. It seems to me like Apache is still listening on those ports even though I have tried to turn it off and running

`$ lsof -i :8080`

returns

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    17586   etc, etc
```

What am I missing here, that will allow me to fully turn off Apache and have it stop effecting that port so that I can directly access my Node process? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was my browser caching, insanely frustrating but true

Comment: This will be the difference between 301 and 302 redirects.  If you use a 301, the browser is supposed to remember the redirect to save the load on the server.  


Most browsers have a developer mode, with a disable cache feature, which can help debug these sorts of issues in the future.